# Iterating over an image in python

Tags: python, image, loops, for-loop, iteration

I would like to iterate over an image in python. 
This is my code so far:

```
def imageIteration(greyValueImage):
    for (x,y), pixel in np.ndenumerate(greyValueImage):
        vals = greyValueImage[x, y]
        print(vals)
```

The problem here ist that I get the following exception:

```
for (x,y), pixel in np.ndenumerate(greyValueImage):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Now my question is what is the fastest way to solve this?
Do I really need to split the image into a few peaces, but taking this step how do I get the count of the necessary loops without trying out?

Thanks for Your ideas

P.s.
im = Image.open(args["image"])
im_grey = im.convert('LA') # convert to grayscale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unpack like that. Just do

```
def imageIteration(greyValueImage):
    for index, pixel in np.ndenumerate(greyValueImage):
        x, y, _ = index
        vals = greyValueImage[x, y]
        print(vals)
```

Because `ndenumerate` returns 2 values list of 2, and number.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html

Comment: Exception:  x, y = index
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @JürgenK. can you do print(index) and see what actually is in this variable?

Comment: @Sardorbeck.     x, y = index
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @JürgenK. Just delete  `x, y = index
        vals = greyValueImage[x, y]
        print(vals)` and do `print(index)`

Comment: Then vals is looking like this(0,0,1), (0,1,1), (0,2,1). But still I need only to iterate over the first two values only

Comment: @JürgenK. See updated answer. It should be `x, y, _ = index` instead of `x, y, = index`

Answer (score 0):

For multiple images, use:

```
for i in range (0, n):
```